# Accessing a django-piston REST API via a django view within the same project

Tags: django, rest, django-views, django-piston

I'm building a small web service. To showcase what the service can do I am going to build a lite-weight interface. I'm having a hard time figuring out how my REST API and regular Django views can play nicely together.

Here's my setup:

Using django-piston to build a simple CRUD REST web service.
Using Django views with httplib2 to GET/POST to/from that web service.
Both are being run from the same Django project (and thus same web server).

Right now I have simple read REST service working in the browser. But when I try to use httplib2 from the Django view the request just hangs.

My questions:
-Am I thinking about this the right way?
-Is there a better way to accomplish this?
-Should my REST web service be a different project (and web server) than my REST interface?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: my guess is that it blocks because it sends another request to your API on the same thread that runs the current request handler. I would call the code that implements your API directly without going through HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I'd demonstrate an API working via unit tests, rather than live views, but can see how that might not be what you need.

So (in line with akonsu's comment above) if you're experiencing this problem local dev, it's the single threaded devserver that's blocking the API from running while the view is executing.

Have you tried a multi-threaded version of the runserver? Like [this one?](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver)